# Does phpDocumentor tags order matter?

Tags: php, documentation

When we document our class, method and/or function with [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html), is there any specific order I should follow according to the standards?

I know it doesn't matter for output the document. Since it is outputting the order what I have written.

This is for my knowledge and understanding if there is any order standards for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such... At least, none that I can find/think of. However, docblocks commonly follow a distinct format/pattern:

```
/**
 * Summary
 * [optional blank line]
 * Description
 * [optional blank line]
 * @see Optional, but more documentation can be added here
 * [optional blank line]
 * @todo: Development docs here
 * [optional blank line]
 * @api indicator of expected/intended usage of code
 * @uses Use-cases of code
 * @property* property-access
 * @deprecated
 * [optional blank line]
 * @param <type> $name [ = default value]
 * @return <return type, if any>
 * @throws <ExceptionType> [optionally explain when and why]
 * @throws <ExceptionType>
 */
```

The logical order here is:

- Summary
- Description
- Annotations documenting the code even more, examples, files, links etc...
- Annotations that document behavior and usage of code ( (like `@see`)
- Annotations regarding ungoing development
- Annotations indicating visibility and expected usage (`@api` or `@internal`) **Structural**
- Annotations indicating internals (dependencies on methods/properties) **Structural**
- Annotations regarding availability (deprecation, preferably mentioning alternatives) **Structural**
- Annotations regarding the function/method's signature (`@param`, then `@return`)
- Annotations covering unexpected behaviour (ie `@throws`)

Some might say that the `@throws` annotation should precede the `@returns`, seeing as the last thing a function *should* do is return something. It is common, though, to put the `@throws` in last. That, to me, makes more sense: the documentation covers the flow of the method you're commenting. If something (an exceptional case) disrupts the flow, an exception is thrown, hence the `@throws` annotation shouldn't be part of the *"normal"* description of the method.

Either way, the simple rule of thumb here is:

- IDE tooltip info comes first (summary, description, `@see`)
- Additional documentation
- Development info (`@todo`, `@example`, possibly `@version`)
- Structural elements (the ones that apply)
- The expected parameters info comes next (`@param`)
- The result (`@return`)
- In case of errors (`@throws`)

Note that the annotations listed here as *Structural elements* require you to document the classes and properties, too: `/** @var <type> */` and, perhaps include `@version` and `@license` tags, too